# Example of longest path problem having a NP complexity?

Tags: graph, theory, proof, np, longest-path

I saw on the internet that finding the longest path problem is NP-Complete problem.

For some reason, my teacher tells me that it isn't an NP-complete problem.
So now I am looking for an example that shows the amount of computation needed for getting the longest path is bigger then polynomial time.

for now, I saw only examples of it having a polynomial complexity time.

anyone can bring me a proof for this problem being NP-complete?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For starters, depending on how you phrase the longest path problem, it may actually be the case that the problem is **NP**-hard but not **NP**-complete. The **NP**-complete version of this problem is the following:

> Given a graph G and a length k, does G have a simple path of length k or more?

This problem is known to be **NP**-complete for reasons I'll detail later on. However, this closely-related problem is *not* actually **NP** complete:

> Given a graph G, what is the longest simple path in G?

This second problem is **NP**-hard but not **NP**-complete. For a problem to be **NP**-complete, the problem has to be a *decision problem*, a problem whose answer is a boolean "yes" or "no." This second version of the problem, however, isn't a decision problem, and so it can't be in **NP**, and so it can't be **NP**-complete. It's entirely possible that your teacher was thinking about this when saying that the longest path problem isn't **NP**-complete, though I can't say for certain.

As for why the longest path problem is **NP**-complete, we need to argue two points:

1. This problem is in **NP**. Intuitively, there's an efficient way to check yes answers to the problem.
2. This problem is **NP**-hard. That is, there's an **NP**-hard problem that reduces to it.

For point (1), the intuition is that if the answer to the question "does this graph have a simple path of length 137 or more?" is "yes," there's some easy way to demonstrate this to someone. Just give them that simple path. Once they have the path, it's easy for them to check that, indeed, it meets the requirements. (Now, *finding* that path might be really hard. But once we've somehow isolated it, it's not hard to convince people that it works.)

For point (2), the general way to do this is to start with an existing **NP**-hard problem and to reduce it to our problem. Here, we'll start with the Hamiltonian path problem, which is the following:

> Given a graph G, is there a simple path that passes through every node in G once and exactly once?

Here's how we reduce that problem to the longest path problem. Start with the graph G. Now, ask the question: does G have a simple path of length at least n - 1, where n is the number of nodes in G? If so, then that simple path has to visit every node once and exactly once, since otherwise there aren't enough nodes in the path to make its length at least n - 1. And conversely, if not, then there's no Hamiltonian path, since any Hamiltonian path would fit the bill. Therefore, if we can solve the longest path problem efficiently, we can solve the Hamiltonian path problem efficiently. Since the Hamiltonian path problem is **NP**-hard, so is the longest path problem.

Now, the fact that this problem is **NP**-complete doesn't mean that there is no polynomial-time solution for it. The **P** versus **NP** problem still hasn't been resolved, and without knowing whether **P** = **NP** or **P** ≠ **NP** we can't say whether there's a polynomial-time algorithm for the longest path problem. What we can say is that no *known* algorithms for it run in polynomial time (you mentioned some sites claim they have polynomial-time algorithms for this problem, but that doesn't sound right; if so, whoever found that algorithm would be a millionaire).

Now, there's a follow-up question you can ask: why is the Hamiltonian path problem **NP**-hard? The usual way to prove this is to start with 3SAT and to do a clever, gadget-based reduction. That's way too long to explore here, but most intro theory textbooks (including Sipser's famous one) do a great job of explaining this.

Comment: This is the site that claims the run time is polynomial.https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/longest-path-between-any-pair-of-vertices/

Comment: That particular post makes the assumption that the graph has no cycles - that is, that the graph is a forest. In that specific case, there is a polynomial-time solution to this problem, but for general graphs this isn’t the case unless P = NP.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: @templatetypedef + I love this confident answer ;)